# codeigniter 3 controller/method validation from config file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not new to CI, but trying something different and moving my validations from my controller (there's lots and its getting messy) to the `form_validation.php` file in the `/application/config` directory.\

The method I am trying to use is the function based on the controller/method where it should auto-load the rules based on where you run `$this->form_validation->run()`

I have read the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#associating-a-controller-method-with-a-rule-group) (many times) and I have seen other posts on stackoverflow and none have given me a solution...

my current setup is below...

application/config/form_validation.php

```
//I know the file is being loaded as these work
$config['error_prefix'] = '<span class="text-danger">';
$config['error_suffix'] = '</span>';

/**
 * METHOD SPECIFIC VALIDATIONS
 */

/* Controller:  Account
 * Method:      Register
 */
$config = array(
'account/register' => array(
        'field' => 'company',
        'label' => 'Company',
        'rules' => 'required|is_unique[company.companyName]',
        array(
            'required' => 'You have not provided {field}.',
            'is_unique' => 'This {field} already exists.'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'username',
        'label' => 'Username',
        'rules' => 'alpha_numeric|trim|required|is_unique[users.username]',
        array(
            'required' => 'You have not provided {field}.',
            'is_unique' => 'This {field} already exists.'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'firstname',
        'label' => 'First Name',
        'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'lastname',
        'label' => 'Last Name',
        'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'password',
        'label' => 'Password',
        'rules' => 'required|min_length[6]',
        array(
            'min_length' => '{field} must have at least {param} characters.'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'passconf',
        'label' => 'Confirm Password',
        'rules' => 'required|matches[password]'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'email',
        'label' => 'Email',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
        array(
            'required' => 'You have not provided {field}.',
            'is_unique' => 'This {field} already exists.'
        )
    )
);
```

Controller:

```
class Account extends CI_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('account_model');
}

public function register()
{
            //Form not yet submitted, user not logged in, display login page
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE and $this->session->userdata('loginuser') == FALSE) {

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('account/register');
        $this->load->view('templates/loadjs');

    } else {
}
```

View Snippet:

```
<input class="form-control" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('company'); ?>" autofocus />
</div>
<div><?php echo form_error('company'); ?></div>
```

Going by the documentation I linked, you should be able to just use `$this->form_validation->run()` and it will auto-call these rules?

Comment: For clarity, can you state your controller and method name? Is it in fact a method named register in a controller named account? Can you show the code where you are calling the validation, and perhaps the html snippet of the form as well? The reason I ask is because on the surface of your description it sounds like you are doing it correctly, but as it is not working, something, somewhere must be incorrect.

Comment: I have done this, please note if I call the validations the normal inline `$this->form_validation->set_rules('company', 'Company', 'required|is_unique[company.companyName]'`method in the controller/view still works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I notice that in your given examples when you call it directly you do not use the error message array that is present in your form_validation.php. Have you tried your form_validation.php file without the defined error message arrays, or conversely, are you also having success using set_message but it is not in your example?

Comment: Sorry, didn't copy that bit, I am using the set error messages in the array directly in the controller and they are working... It's very strange

Comment: Have you tried removing the session data part of the conditional just to rule out that as the reason the validation does not run?

Comment: Or, have you verified the presence of that session variable with the profiler output?

Comment: The session variable isn't the issue, I think I worked it out. I was over-writing the $config array using the method in the guide as I assume they are presuming that you are not using any other settings in form_validation.php

Comment: Glad you found it. That thought crossed my mind but I did not see it in the code you posted. I have noticed when overriding a config array you often have to re-include things you are not overriding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those playing at home the answer was that I was over-writing the $config array with my original method. As the validation file is included and not separate, it assigns rather than appends the $config array.

```
$config['account/register'] = array(
    array(
        'field' => 'company',
        'label' => 'Company',
        'rules' => 'required|is_unique[company.name]',
        'errors' => array(
            'required' => 'You have not provided {field}.',
            'is_unique' => 'This {field} already exists.'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'username',
        'label' => 'Username',
        'rules' => 'alpha_numeric|trim|required|is_unique[users.username]',
        'errors' => array(
            'required' => 'You have not provided {field}.',
            'is_unique' => 'This {field} already exists.'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'firstname',
        'label' => 'First Name',
        'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'lastname',
        'label' => 'Last Name',
        'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'password',
        'label' => 'Password',
        'rules' => 'required|min_length[5]',
        'errors' => array(
            'min_length' => '{field} must have at least {param} characters.'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'passconf',
        'label' => 'Confirm Password',
        'rules' => 'required|matches[password]'
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'email',
        'label' => 'Email',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
        'errors' => array(
            'required' => 'You have not provided {field}.',
            'is_unique' => 'This {field} already exists.'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code again, I think I see a mismatch. I see that you are loading the form_validation as a library, however that should mean there is something in the library folder you are not showing us, or maybe you meant to use a config class instead to access it since it is in the config folder. If that is true you might want to look at the [config class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html).

Comment: The issue is right there in the code I wrote all that time ago `$config = array()` this is overwriting the whole $config array. I'll add an answer